# how it's possible some redirects not works?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 types of redirect that all same and simple but number2 not work !

```
Redirect /post/view/231کاملترین-لیست-قیمت-اسکوتر-برقی-97 https://irscooter.com/post/category/2


Redirect /product/category?id=75 https://irscooter.com/product/category/75
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not redirect URL with querystring using `Redirect` . Anything after `?` in URL is a querystring and can only be accessed using `%{QUERY_STRING}` mod-rewrite variable .

So you need to use something like the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=75$
RewriteRule ^product/category/?$ https://irscooter.com/product/category/75? [L,R]
```

Comment: thank you very much it's work , but in some utf url as like in my example it's not works , do you know why ?